# Visual Studio 2017 automatically adding call to AddRange resulting in Exception at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated to Visual Studio 2017 and have been having an issue working with designer files ever since.

for some control `cmbExample` in a `Designer.cs` file defined using a `DataSource` like so:

```
this.cmbExample.DataSource = new object[] {((object)("Primary"))};
this.cmbExample.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```

Visual Studio 2017 is automatically adding an additional call to `AddRange()` on my control like so:

```
this.cmbExample.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"Primary"});
```

At runtime it results in `ArgumentException`:

```
Exception: System.ArgumentException: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.CheckNoDataSource()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.ObjectCollection.AddRange(Object[] items)
```

Is there a setting I can change to prevent VS from automatically adding the call to `AddRange()`?

This infuriating problem has been torturing my teammates and I for a while now, especially because there are a lot of controls in this specific application.

Comment: Did you specify items in the designer?

Comment: I have not. The items are defined by the `DataSource` only. The project builds fine in VS13/15 without this issue.